# Java SHA1withRSA verification is always false, why?

Tags: java, security, rsa, sha1, verification

I'm doing a SHA1withRSA verification method but the result is always false, is it something I coded wrong or are the public keys wrong or something?

Here's the code:

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
File file = this.getPublicKey();
byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

// Setup RSA key
X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

// verify signatures
byte[] signatureBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(this.firmaB64);
signature.initVerify(publicKey);
signature.update(this.parteFirmada.getBytes());
boolean result = signature.verify(signatureBytes);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This `this.parteFirmada.getBytes()` may not give you the exact bytes that were originally signed. At least specify the character encoding explicitly, but better use the original bytes (before they were converted to a string).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That string is originally from a larger string which contained both the parteFirmada String and the firmaB64 String, should I use substring from the original and get both of these strings and bytes arrays?

Comment: What is actually signed are bytes, not a string. How do you get the `parteFirmada`? If it is transferred as string, be sure to use the exact same character encoding that was used by the signer.

Comment: Both the `parteFirmada` and `firmaB64` comes from a single string which is split by # so the first element is the signed piece and the second one is the signature

Comment: Probably the problem is in obtaining `parteFirmada` from that string. Make sure it corresponds with the original. Check also if you need to decode from base64 as you do with the signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that **the string that I was verifying was not as the original string that was signed** and hence that it was false. **The verification code was good** in case anyone is interested.

The string contained a timestamp and to pass the timestamp verification it was changed... that could never pass as verified!

Thanks for all the comments